# How to add Total column from table with similar order ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing difficulty in writing a query to fetch SUM of Total column for similar order ID's. Find below my attached dataset.

```
col_order_id            col_Sku         col_quantity    col_total
--------------------------------------------------------------------
171-0018081-8109151     NULL            0                -76.7
171-0018081-8109151     9GT99           1                847.96
408-7394176-7348346     6TM1C-59        1                  0
171-0018081-8109151     NULL            0                -76.7
171-0018081-8109151     9GT99           1                847.96
403-2182954-9305131     MGJN9+PC-15     1               1032.29
```

Query:

```sql
select * 
from tbl_Payment_Reports
group by col_order_id
having count(col_order_id) > 1
```

I tried using the above query but getting an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Column 'tbl_Payment_Reports.col_date_time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: When using `GROUP BY`, use aggregation functions such as `SUM()`.

Comment: basically your query is missing SUM(col_total) which is what you re trying to obtain

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:
`select sum(col_total)
from tbl_Payment_Reports
group by col_order_id
having count(col_order_id) > 1`

Comment: I need a sum of duplicate Order Id's and a just of single order id as well. only duplicate order id's total has to be summed up rest order id's total must be the same and all order ID's must be displayed with their total.